# How to organize tests and PageObject classes with FluentAutomation and MSTest (Cannot resolve symbol "I" error)

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, fluentautomation

I am trying to run the example in the documentation [here](http://fluent.stirno.com/docs/#pageobjects).

I am using Visual Studio with MSTest, so I modified the code a little bit and it looks like this now:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using FluentAutomation;
using FluentAutomation.Interfaces;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;

namespace UnitTestProject1
{
    public class BingSearchPage : PageObject
    {
        public BingSearchPage(FluentTest test)
            : base(test)
    {
        Url = "http://bing.com/";
        At = () => I.Expect.Exists(SearchInput); //Documentation says "At = () =>; I.Expect.Exists(SearchInput);" but I think that's a typo
    }

        public BingSearchResultsPage Search(string searchText)
        {
            I.Enter(searchText).In(SearchInput);
            I.Press("{ENTER}");
            return this.Switch();
        }

        private const string SearchInput = "input[title='Enter your search term']";
    }

    public class BingSearchResultsPage : PageObject
    {
        public BingSearchResultsPage(FluentTest test)
            : base(test)
        {
            At = () => I.Expect.Exists(SearchResultsContainer);
        }

        public BingSearchResultsPage FindResultUrl(string url)
        {
            I.Expect.Exists(string.Format(ResultUrlLink, url));
            return this;
        }

        private const string SearchResultsContainer = "#b_results";
        private const string ResultUrlLink = "a[href='{0}']";
    }

    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1 : FluentTest
    {
        public UnitTest1()
        {
            SeleniumWebDriver.Bootstrap(SeleniumWebDriver.Browser.Chrome);
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void SearchForFluentAutomation()
        {
            new BingSearchPage(this)
                .Go()
                .Search("FluentAutomation")
                .FindResultUrl("http://fluent.stirno.com/blog/FluentAutomation-scriptcs/");
        }
    }
}
```

I get errors like:

> Error 1   'FluentAutomation.PageObject' does not contain a constructor
>   that takes 1 arguments    C:\Users\Shitij\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\UnitTestProject1\UnitTestProject1\UnitTest1.cs  13  15  UnitTestProject1
>
> Error 2   The name 'I' does not exist in the current
>   context   C:\Users\Shitij\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\UnitTestProject1\UnitTestProject1\UnitTest1.cs  16  20  UnitTestProject1
>
> Error 3   'UnitTestProject1.BingSearchPage' does not contain a
>   definition for 'Switch' and no extension method 'Switch' accepting a
>   first argument of type 'UnitTestProject1.BingSearchPage' could be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)   C:\Users\Shitij\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\UnitTestProject1\UnitTestProject1\UnitTest1.cs  23  25  UnitTestProject1

Feels like a stupid question, but I am stuck on it. Any idea what I am doing wrong? The property "I" seems to be in FluentTest class, so how is the documentation using that in classes derived from PageObject?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theres an issue with the docs on the site atm. Really need to get it fixed. The generic bits are missing!

change `PageObject` to `PageObject<BingSearchResultsPage>` and `I` should resolve.

Comment: Thanks! :D Actually I found a github page in which you had the correct working example. Maybe just paste that in the documentation?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, this is what I came up with:

```
using System;
using FluentAutomation;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace HelloWorldTests
{
    [TestClass]
    public class WithPageObjectTests : FluentTest
    {
        public WithPageObjectTests()
        {
            SeleniumWebDriver
                .Bootstrap(SeleniumWebDriver.Browser.InternetExplorer);
        }

        [TestInitialize]
        public void TestInitialisze()
        {
            // Global wait timer
            Config.Settings.WaitUntilTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);

            Config.Settings.ScreenshotOnFailedAction = true;
            Config.Settings.ScreenshotOnFailedAssert = true;
            Config.Settings.ScreenshotOnFailedExpect = true;
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void SearchForFluentAutomation()
        {
            new BingSearchPage(this)
                .Go()
                .Search("FluentAutomation")
                .FindResultUrl("http://fluent.stirno.com/blog/FluentAutomation-scriptcs/");
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Page model
    /// </summary>
    public class BingSearchPage : PageObject<BingSearchPage>
    {
        //private const string SearchInput = "input[title='Enter your search term']";
        private const string SearchInput = "#sb_form_q";

        public BingSearchPage(FluentTest test)
            : base(test)
        {
            Url = "http://bing.com/";
            At = () => I.Expect.Exists(SearchInput);
        }

        public BingSearchResultsPage Search(string searchText)
        {
            I.Enter(searchText).In(SearchInput);
            I.Press("{ENTER}");
            return this.Switch<BingSearchResultsPage>();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Page model
    /// </summary>
    public class BingSearchResultsPage : PageObject<BingSearchResultsPage>
    {
        private const string SearchResultsContainer = "#b_results";
        private const string ResultUrlLink = "a[href='{0}']";

        public BingSearchResultsPage(FluentTest test)
            : base(test)
        {
            At = () => I.Expect.Exists(SearchResultsContainer);
        }

        public BingSearchResultsPage FindResultUrl(string url)
        {
            I.Expect.Exists(string.Format(ResultUrlLink, url));
            return this;
        }
    }
}
```